# ISP gave me one public IP (WAN) AND a block of public IPs for use

Tags: ip, cisco, router, ip-address, isp

I have been given a range of public IPs from my ISP, plus a single IP they route to.  What's the best way to go about this?  Not looking to firewall or NAT, just distribute the IPs to two different firewalls and a Velos.

Example:
IPv4 WAN: 123.45.67.89/31 GW:123.45.67.89 Useable: 123.45.67.90 Subnet: 255.255.255.254

IPV4 LAN: 234.56.78.90/29 Useable: 234.56.78.91-234.56.78.96 Broadcast: 234.56.78.97 Subnet: 255.255.255.248

Never had to deal with public addresses on both sides.  Really don't want to NAT to private.

Also, any suggestions on a rather inexpensive but reliable router for this?

Comment: This is not the right place to ask for product recommendations. But, I'd think of some Mikrotik hardware. Any RouterOS device is easy to set up to work like you want; choose the one which matches your throughput requirements.

Comment: OK, sorry about that.  First post here.